# Configure nginx running locally to server the port running docker container locally

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, gateway, containers

Hi this may be a noob question.

I am trying to replicate a 502 bad gateway error when using nginx as a web server. I have locally running VM of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on which I have freshly installed nginx using

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

then

`nginx -v` which returned

> `nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

and verified that it is running by the command

`systemctl status nginx` that shows that it is running.

Then I created a docker container with a simple Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Node.js image with Alpine Linux as the base image
FROM node:14-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the app will run on
EXPOSE 9000

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

And this is the app.js file

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 9000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello, Docker World!</h1>');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

When I access the localhost:9000 it returns the web page saying 'Hello, Docker World!'

Next I want to serve this localhost:9000 using the nginx web server. Then I will shutdown the docker container in an attempt to generate  bad gateway error response from nginx web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, open the configuration file located at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.

Check the file's content; you will easily find a `location /`. Add these three proxy lines inside the `location /`.

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

Then, restart the Nginx service, and you will be good to go.

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Check out the tutorial for a case study on Nginx reverse proxy:
How to Set Up Nginx Reverse Proxy Servers by Example"

Comment: Thank you so much. This replicated the behavior I wanted..

1. Added the configuration to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

2. Restarted the nginx server with `systemctl restart nginx`

3. Started the docker container `docker start keen_litcherman` that started LISTENING at port 9000

4. `localhost` redirected to the docker container and displayed "Hello, Docker World!"

5. Stopped the container

6. Upon refreshing the page `localhost` the server returned 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the docker container 9000 port to your localhost. Use the following command for binding.

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 <your_container_image>
```

Comment: I have already done this and the docker container is accessible on localhost:9000. I want to add this address to nginx such that when I open localhost in browser it would connect to the localhost:9000 and return its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added these lines in your nginx configuration for configuring reverse proxy from 9000 to 80 port.

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

If already added this share your output of `nginx -t` command and also check your logs

Comment: Can you please guide me as to how to do this. The documentation was not very clear about where to set this up. I am not very familiar with nginx. Where in nginx do I set up the reverse proxy and what to use in `/some/path`